# Subquery necessary for comparison?

Tags: mysql, sql

Goal:

Need results for channels that are active (`channels.active=1`) but have `0` active items.

There are `items` and they belong in `channel`. `items` can have multiple channels.

There are 3 tables:

- `channels`
- `items`
- `items_channels`

The `items_channel` maps items to channels. Example row:

```
id  item   channel
1   23     47
```

So far I just have this to get active channels:

`SELECT * FROM channels WHERE channels.active = 1`

I'm having trouble grasping the part where I only join the channels that have 0 active items - do I need a subquery or a `HAVING` clause that has a `COUNT` somewhere?

Also, `channels.active` is for active channels, and `items.active` is for active items.

Comment: Thank goodness SO doesn't give badges for profile views. I guess that 85% of those 13,845 is because of your avatar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT channels.* 
FROM channels
LEFT JOIN items_channels
  ON channels.id = items_channels.channel
LEFT JOIN items
  ON items_channels.item = items.id AND items.active = 1
WHERE channels.active = 1
GROUP BY channels.id
HAVING COUNT(items.id) = 0
```

Working sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ee64/1).

Comment: I don't know mySql, but is this query correct without GROUP BY statement?

Comment: It is actually valid in MySQL - however it won't return the right results in this case without it.  Fixed.

Comment: But meder needs all channel data. This will require use of nested queries, right?

Comment: No, not in MySQL - you can GROUP on just the elements you think are unique to the group and it will trust you.  Updated sqlfiddle to demonstrate this.

Comment: While this may work in MySQL, it is not correct. You should not `SELECT` any columns which are not in your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @njk: In this case, the GROUP BY is on the table primary key, so the meaning would be exactly the same had all columns been listed.  Can you demonstrate that your statement applies in this case with any facts or resources?

Comment: @PinnyM [This example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c8f9/1) demonstrates that you cannot select columns which are not in the `GROUP BY`. MySQL [extends this functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//group-by-extensions.html) for convenience; but it's not ANSI standard.

Comment: @njk: Granted it's not ANSI standard and won't work in SQL Server (or most other DBMS's) - but is it problematic to use in a MySQL environment?  The OP didn't state that the code needs to be portable...

Comment: In my opinion, it's poor practice. Portability is certainly a valid argument, but I would argue for the sake of the developer should they have to ever work on another platform.

Comment: @njk: I agree that it's poor practice to use indiscriminately.  In this case - that is, grouping on the primary key and selecting columns from that table only - I don't think there's anything wrong with it.  And for a 20+ column table, that can leave a developer much happier and less error-prone :)

Comment: I still disagree. The developer should use standard and better practice rather than convenience. Further, depending on the platform there may be advantages to specifying a column list.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM channels c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN items_channels ic ON c.channelID = ic.channelID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN items i ON i.itemID = ic.itemID AND i.active = 1
WHERE channels.active = 1 AND i.itemID IS NULL
```

If you use COUNT() you would need to use nested queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM channels c
WHERE channels.active = 1 AND c.channelID IN 
    (
    SELECT ic.channelID FROM items_channels ic 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN items i ON i.itemID = ic.itemID
        WHERE i.active = 1
    GROUP BY ic.channelID
    HAVING COUNT(ic.itemID) == 0
    )
```

Comment: You don't need the second join onto `items`. If there are no items, there are no entries in the join table `items_channels`, so you're not interested in getting the item details. Or if the OP wanted "0 active items", you should add an `i.active = 1`.

Comment: Wouldn't I need it to check for active items, Borealid? There can be mapping to items that are inactive. The `items.active` column determines active or not.

Comment: Updated answer to check for active items only.

Comment: There is no need to use DISTINCT since when there will be no items for paticular channel there will be only one record for this channel (values for other tables will be NULL).

Comment: semao. yes, distinct is not needed +1

Comment: semao, with mysql [hiddens fields](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/6.0/en/group-by-hidden-fields.html) subquery is not needed.

Comment: `SELECT ic.channelID FROM items_channels ic ON c.channelID = ic.channelID` - that's supposed to be a `LEFT JOIN` on `c`?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste mistake. Updated the answer. Thanks meder.